# News gallery & canonical tag

Tags: html, seo, canonical-link

I have a news site about global sport industry. There are news, and some of the news have galleries, such as:

News URL:

```
example.com/news/tiger-woods-win-the-cup
```

Gallery URLs:

```
example.com/news/tiger-woods-win-the-cup/1
example.com/news/tiger-woods-win-the-cup/2
example.com/news/tiger-woods-win-the-cup/3
```

**Should I add `canonical` tag into the gallery HTML as like below?**

```html
<link rel="canonical" 
href="http://www.example.com/news/tiger-woods-win-the-cup" />
```

Note: gallery pages have no written content except of the same news headline; it's all photographs (1.jpg, 2.jpg etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all photographs also included on `/news/tiger-woods-win-the-cup`?

If no:
You [must not](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596#section-3) use the `canonical` link type, because you news page doesn’t "identify content that is either duplicative or a superset of the content at the context (referring) IRI" (which would be your gallery pages).

If yes:
You may use the `canonical` link type.